# Order two geometric/linear sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(u_n)_{n\geq 0}$ a sequence of reals satisfying the following recurrence relation:

$$ 
\forall n>1, \qquad u_{n+2} = r^{n+2}\big( Au_{n+1}+ Bu_n\big)
$$

for fixed non zero constants $A,B,r$. Is there a closed form expression of the (2 dimensional) space of solutions, parametrised by the initial values $u_0, u_1$?

My observation is that the set of solution is a 2 dimensional vector space, so that we would only need to find the solutions for the initial parameters $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ and then express the generic solution as a linear combination of these twos. Point is is can't find a sympathetic expression for the elements of this bases.

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if you mention your thoughts and what you have tried to answer the question.

Comment: You're right, I edited my message!

Answer (score 1):

Look for solutions of the form $u_n=a^n$ for some (in general complex) number $a\ne0$. You will get a quadratic equation for $a$. If it has two different solutions $a_1$ and $a_2$, then $a_1^n$ and $a_2^n$ are two linearly independent solutions and the general solution is $u_n=C_1\,a_1^n+C_2\,a_2^n$. I leave to you the case when there is only one solution to the quadratic equation.

Comment: Solutions can't be written in such a form: the equation would be $z^2=r^{n+2} (Az+B)$ for any $n$, which is valid iff $z=0$.

Comment: Ríght. I treated the equation as ir $r^{n+2}$ were constant.

Comment: Mathematica does not find an explicit solution